# Detecting second tap on tab bar item when first one triggers popToRootViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I want to implement scrolling to top of view controller when user taps on tab bar item in tab bar. I do it by overriding `tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool` method in `UITabBarControllerDelegate`.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    // Scroll to top only if we are already on given tab
    if viewControllers?.firstIndex(of: viewController) == selectedIndex {
        // Checks if root VC of navigation controller is currently shown and then scrolls it to top
        scrollToTop(at: selectedIndex)
    }

    return true
}
```

Each tab has navigation controller as its view controller and tapping on tab bar causes pop to root view controller. It's fine and desired, but I want a double tap to work, i.e. user is in second (or later) view in navigation controller, double taps on tab bar and then navigation controller pops and root view controller scrolls to top (first tap pops to root view controller and second one scrolls to top).

Unfortunately, this delegate method is called only once when such scenario happens. It starts detecting next taps on tab bar items only after pop transition ends.
Double tapping works fine when switching tabs, i.e. user is on tab B, double taps tab A, and then first tap switches to tab A and second one scrolls makes it scroll to top.

I checked Facebook and Twitter apps, and both of them correctly handle quick double tap - they pop and then scroll to top.

Is there a way to detect tab bar items taps when pop transition is in progress? I tried overriding `tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem)` of `UITabBarController` but it's also not called twice on double tap in aforementioned scenario. Adding custom double tap recognizer also does not help as it significantly delays single taps to tab bar which causes app to look laggy.

Comment: on viewWillAppear you can scroll to top

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya that's not an option. This would cause scrolling to top on each tab change or when user pops view controller in navigation controller and that's not what I want to achieve.

Comment: You can add gesture recogniser on `tabbar` did you try that ?

Comment: As I wrote in my question, yes I did.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Notification for this case. 
First, create extension for your Notification.Name :

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static var userDoubleTapTabbar: Notification.Name {
       return .init(rawValue: "User.DoubleTapTabbar")
    }
}
```

Then, In your Tabbar Controller, detect your user double tap items event and fire notification:

```
public var lastTabbarItem: UITabBarItem?
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    SEManager.shared.playSound(type: .tap_bottom_tap)
    if self.lastTabbarItem == item {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .userDoubleTapTabbar, object: nil)
    }
    self.lastTabbarItem = item
}
```

Then in your Tabbar item view controller, you can add observer & handler for that notification to scroll your table view to top. You can use this to check if that Tabbar item view controller is current visible:

```
if viewController.viewIfLoaded?.window != nil {
   // viewController is visible
}
```

Hope it helps and sorry for my bad English.